# controller get wrong id from view when submit form in codeigniter

Tags: php, bootstrap-4, codeigniter-3

I'm pretty new to codeigniter and quite new to PHP. I want to delete a record from the DB and directory. data is delete from database and directory.when i submit,delete is success but delete always choose last item from table database to delete not from id in view i choose to delete. Here is my code

1. view.php

```
<?php foreach ($data as $row) : ?>
    <div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal<?= $row['id']; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="deleteModalLabel">Ready to delete?</h5>
                    <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <?php echo form_open('admin/slider_delete'); ?>
                    <input type="text" name="id" id="id" value="<?= $row['id']; ?>">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="slider_name" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Slider Name</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="slider_name" id="slider_name" value="<?= $row['slider_name']; ?>" readonly>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="slider_image" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Image</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <div class="custom-file">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="slider_image" name="slider_image" value="<?= $row['slider_image']; ?>" readonly>
                                        <img src="<?= base_url('assets/img/slider/') . $row['slider_image']; ?>" id="image-preview" alt="image preview" class="img-thumbnail" style="width : 100px;height:60px;">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br><br><br>Are you sure to delete this data?
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button> </div>
                <?= var_dump($row); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

2. controller.php

```
    public function slider_delete()
    {
        $id = $this->input->post('id');
        $slider = $this->input->post('slider_image');
        $data = [
            'slider_name' => htmlspecialchars($this->input->post('slider_name', true)),
            'slider_link' => htmlspecialchars($this->input->post('slider_link', true)),
            'text_active' => 1,
            'title_text' => htmlspecialchars_decode($this->input->post('title_text', true)),
            'description' => htmlspecialchars_decode($this->input->post('description', true)),
            'is_active' => 1
        ];
        echo var_dump($id, $data, $slider);
        die;
        $this->slider_model->delete($id, $data, $slider);

        $this->session->set_flashdata('massage', '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"> Slider has been delete!</div>');
        redirect('admin/slider');
    }
```

3. model.php

```
    public function delete($id, $data, $slider)
    {
        $this->db->set($data);
        $this->db->where('id', $id);

        unlink(FCPATH . 'assets/img/slider/' . $slider);
        $this->db->delete('slider');
}
```

Comment: You are adding row id in loop. So, only latest will be posted.

Comment: Prolly you should make each iteration of the loop it's own form.

Comment: thanks all, i already got answer, i forgot put </form> in view...now is back to normal delete :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code you are creating a new form for every row, but you aren't closing the form. Thus the ID variable is always the last one set before the inferred closed form tag. After the line

```
<br><br><br>Are you sure to delete this data?
```

Add

```
</form>
```

Then check your code that is displayed to the browser. You should have the equivalent opening form tags to closing form tags.